# How to read image from raw UDP packets (captured from SharpPcap)

Tags: image, sharppcap

I send a Bitmap image from virtual machine to local machine, then capture the image UDP packets by SharpPcap from local machine. But I don't know how to get rid of those protocol header and get the image displayed.

In fact, I need to read Gbytes image from Ethernet card and display it in real-time. So I want to read the raw image data from Ethernet card by SharpPcap, keep it in the system buffer and display it in the GUI. Is my current method right?

Comment: How do you send the bitmap image exactly?

Comment: I copy image through shared file between virtual machine and PC. I know it's actually TCP transport. But I prefer to know how to extract image from UDP packet @kol

Comment: I think you don't really need SharpPcap. (1) If you use file copy, then the OS will decode the traffic and write the file to hard disk for you. (2) If you don't want to use shared files and file copying, then implement your own socket communication to transport the image.